# Docker run normally but docker ps show nothing

Tags: ubuntu, docker

`docker run` not working on my machine (Ubuntu 16.04).

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I did not understand the question correctly. What you want to do is bash connection maybe parameter to execute is incorrect

```
sudo docker run -t -i /bin/bash ubuntu
```

Go for it

Comment: I got `docker: Error parsing reference: "/bin/bash" is not a valid repository/tag.
See 'docker run --help'.`
 but
`sudo docker run -d -it ubuntu` work for me.

Comment: Than you want ssh connect using this command `sudo docker attach ubuntu`

Comment: got `Error: No such container: ubuntu`

Comment: Something seems to be a problem `sudo docker pull ubuntu` Try this command

Comment: @SeonggwonYoon, it must be `ubuntu /bin/bash`, not: `/bin/bash ubuntu`

Answer (score 11):

It's likely `docker run` did work, but since you did not specify any command to run, the container stopped working just after starting. With `docker ps -a` you should see some exited ubuntu containers.

If you run the container as daemon (`-d`) and tell it to wait for interactive input (`-it`) it should stay running. Hence `docker run -d -it ubuntu` should do what you want.

Comment: it seems you see the problem, please provide a good good command that allow me to run the image in background so I can mark your answer is correct.

Comment: Extremely helpful answer!

Answer (score 1):

```
docker run -dit ubuntu
docker exec -it ubuntu bash
```

OR

```
docker run -dit ubuntu bash
```

Above is the basic command. You can add ports and volumes to it as per need.

Comment: What does the -dit do?