# Running docker 1.13.1 container as daemon and telling to wait for interactive input - still stops

Tags: docker

I have done like here:

[Docker run normally but docker ps show nothing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45098506/docker-run-normally-but-docker-ps-show-nothing)

```
sudo docker run -dit $DOCKERID/symfony_3_subscribers_in_file_demo
```

It gives output long string of letters and numbers

When I run

```
sudo docker ps
```

there are no running containers. If I run

```
sudo docker ps -a
```

there are containers with status Exited (1)

Dockerfile:

```
FROM 1and1internet/ubuntu-16-apache-php-7.2:latest

COPY . /var/www/demo

EXPOSE 80
```

What is wrong here?

**Update**

Even when commenting out all lines besides

```
EXPOSE 80
```

then building image:

```
sudo docker image build --tag $DOCKERID/symfony_3_subscribes_in_file_demo .
```

and running same way the container - nothing changes, process still stops.

**Update**

As Maxim Zaslavsky wrote, checked the log - it shows:

> standard_ini_linux.go:178: exec user process caused "exec format error"

Comment: What is the host OS, CPU architecture, and Docker version installed on the host? This sounds like you are running amd64 binaries on arm64.

Comment: Host machine you mean probably what docker see. In reality it is virtual machine. It is Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS. CPU architecture: if I run arch in terminal - it shows i686. Docker version - 1.13.1. I tried to install higher, but did not manage to. The latest version requires 64 bit ubuntu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`ubuntu-16-apache-php-7.2`](https://github.com/1and1internet/ubuntu-16-apache-php-7.2/blob/master/Dockerfile) image is built on top of [`ubuntu-16-apache`](https://github.com/1and1internet/ubuntu-16-apache/blob/master/Dockerfile), itself on top of [`ubuntu-16`](https://github.com/1and1internet/ubuntu-16/blob/master/Dockerfile).

That last images includes:

```
ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/bash", "-e", "/init/entrypoint"]
CMD ["run"]
```

with [this as an entrypoint script](https://github.com/1and1internet/ubuntu-16/blob/master/files/init/entrypoint).

> I tried to install higher, but did not manage to. The latest version requires 64 bit ubuntu.

That seems to be the issue here: the image assumes a 64-bits host, but your Ubuntu VM is [32-bits: try with a 64-bits one instead](https://askubuntu.com/a/992019/5470).

The base ubuntu-16 image is built on top of [Ubuntu-xenial](https://github.com/tianon/docker-brew-ubuntu-core/blob/1637ff264a1654f77807ce53522eff7f6a57b773/xenial/Dockerfile), marked as:

> Update to 20171214 for amd64 (amd64)

If you cannot see an option for 64-bits in your VirtualBox, it probably is because [Intel VT-x/AMD-V is not yet enabled in the the BIOS](https://askubuntu.com/a/142790/5470).

Comment: Oh, so its the only option? I really did not want to waste time by reinstaling, plus the virtual box shows only 32 bit option in the dropdown, so I need to find how to fix it.

Comment: @Darius.V To fix it (meaning allowing you to see 64-bits) https://askubuntu.com/a/142790/5470

Comment: I checked the BIOS, but did not found the option to enable Intel VT-x in my Acer 5749Z laptop. So probably it does not support 64 bit virtualization. But at least I know it is not possible to fix. So I have to choose some other image. Btw I thought docker is for making it work on any linux machine, but as I understand now bits have to match.

Comment: @Darius.V would https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=09GZtiK4OrI help (to be adapted to 5749 instead of the 5742 shown in the video). But yes... https://icecat.us/en-in/p/acer/lx.rr802.015/notebook-portatili-5749Z-B954G50Mikk-14716101.html shows VT-x not supported

Comment: watched few minutes, but I do not feel like installing some modified BIOS which is risky, I might end up screwing things to who knows what state and end up wasting too much time. Probably better to choose some other image.

Comment: I agree, I was just checking all options

Answer (score 1):

`Exited (1)` means the process in the container exited with code 1, likely meaning an error occurred.

You can peek into the logs as follows:

```
docker run -d -it --name my-container $DOCKERID/symfony_3_subscribers_in_file_demo   # name it
docker ps -a               # check to see whether it exited
docker logs my-container   # look up the logs for this container
```

Comment: Updated the question with the log output