# How to find docker parent images?

Tags: docker

Here is the example how VonC found which are base images: [Running docker 1.13.1 container as daemon and telling to wait for interactive input - still stops](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48174393/running-docker-1-13-1-container-as-daemon-and-telling-to-wait-for-interactive-in)

I now want to find image which fits i686 architecture. So I need to find parent images.

For example I saw this Dockerfile:

https://github.com/webdevops/Dockerfile/blob/master/docker/php-dev/7.2/Dockerfile

There is line

```
FROM webdevops/php:7.2
```

How do I find base image? I tried to enter

```
webdevops/php:7.2
```

to hub.docker.com search bar, but it just gives me lot of results and I cannot find which one is what I am looking for.

Comment: If your image is `webdevops/php`, then you want https://hub.docker.com/r/webdevops/php/.  The `7.2` is a tag, which you will find in that repository.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition of https://hub.docker.com/r/webdevops/php/, you will find php:7.2 [refers to php-official:7.2](https://github.com/webdevops/Dockerfile/blob/master/docker/php/7.2), with:

- [php-official 7.2 Dockerfile](https://github.com/webdevops/Dockerfile/blob/master/docker/php-official/7.2/Dockerfile#L30), which is `FROM php:7.2-fpm`
- that is [`docker-library/php/7.2/stretch/fpm/Dockerfile`](https://github.com/docker-library/php/blob/f4baf0edbc4e05e241938c68bcc7c9635707583d/7.2/stretch/fpm/Dockerfile), which is `FROM debian:stretch-slim`,
- That is: [debuerreotype/docker-debian-artifacts/stretch/slim/Dockerfile](https://github.com/debuerreotype/docker-debian-artifacts/blob/6af0f6159c515601731d92972a245199337e3ca6/stretch/slim/Dockerfile), which starts from SCRATCH.

Note: some of those images are [multi-stage built](https://blog.docker.com/2017/07/multi-stage-builds/), which is to say they are using the `FROM xxx AS yyy` syntax:

- `FROM xxx` means "I am building image `xxx`".
- `FROM xxx AS yyy` meaning "I am building an intermediate image from `xxx`, named `yyy`, from which I will copy some files in order to build my actual image `zzz`".

You can try and replicate those image, but starting [from an i686 one](https://hub.docker.com/u/i686/), in your case [i686/ubuntu](https://hub.docker.com/r/i686/ubuntu/) for instance.

Comment: I did not get - how do you find that in addition to https://hub.docker.com/r/webdevops/php/ is php-official 7.2 Dockerfile ?

Comment: I look at the Dockerfile (that I mention in the answer), then I look into docker.hub again

Comment: Ok, you pick different Dockerfile than in my question. So you say it is FROM php:7.2-fpm but I see it is FROM webdevops/toolbox . I am looking at the same you mentioned: https://github.com/webdevops/Dockerfile/blob/master/docker/php-official/7.2/Dockerfile

Where do you see  FROM php:7.2-fpm ?

Comment: @Darius.V I pick the exact same Dockerfie than in your question, then I look where it came from. https://github.com/webdevops/Dockerfile/blob/master/docker/php-official/7.2/Dockerfile#L30 => php 7.2

Comment: @Darius.V This is a multi-stage build (https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/eng-image/multistage-build/) you are looking at [line 8](https://github.com/webdevops/Dockerfile/blob/master/docker/php-official/7.2/Dockerfile#L8). I am looking at [line 30](https://github.com/webdevops/Dockerfile/blob/master/docker/php-official/7.2/Dockerfile#L30)

Comment: Aha. So how do you decide that you need to look at FROM php:7.2-fpm instead of FROM webdevops/toolbox ? Or now should I look at both paths till the end?

Comment: @Darius.V Because when I see `FROM xxx AS yyy`, I know it is a multi-stage build, meaning the actual image being build is *not* `xxx`, but `zzz`, which is defined later below in the same Dockerfile, `FROM zzz`, with some `COPY --from=yyy`. That was introduced in July 2017: https://blog.docker.com/2017/07/multi-stage-builds/

Comment: @Darius.V `FROM xxx` means "I am building image `xxx`". `FROM xxx AS yyy` meaning "I am building an *intermediate* image from `xxx`, named `yyy`, from which I will copy some files in order to build my actual image `zzz`".

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163110/discussion-between-darius-v-and-vonc).